# HTML Converter abandoned in Java 7?

Tags: java, applet

It's not longer there in the bin folder of Java 7. Do I go with the `<applet>` tag again? What about messages if Java is not installed? It is strange that this is omitted now, have to change the build process then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to launch your applet (or JWS app.).  Also mentioned as the 5<sup>th</sup> link in the 'See also' section of the [info. on the applet tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).